# ssh message after login but before password

Tags: ssh, motd

Is it possible to make a message appear for each user after he entered his login but before he needs to enter his password?
I looked at `motd` and issue files, but I could not set it up, how I want.
Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `Banner` directive in `sshd_config`:

```
vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config
#add
Banner /etc/banner.txt
```

Create the file `/etc/banner.txt` with the content you want to display.

Reload the `sshd` service to make the changes effective.

You can even create different banners for different users or groups by using the `Banner` directive within a `Match` group i.e.:

```
Match User myuser
    Banner /etc/banner-for-myuser
```

Or

```
Match Group mygroup
    Banner /etc/banner-for-mygroup
```

Comment: Works great! Thanks! Only one moment: match rules work only if they at the BOTTOM of sshd_config.

Comment: @Ole once you use a `match` statement it applies to everything forward from that point until another `match` statement or the end of file,.

Comment: And note that not all directives are allowed after the `Match` directive, see the explanation of the `Match` directive in the manual `man sshd_config`